# How to tag a Git repo from Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, git

It might be silly, but i just can't figure it out:

i added git support for my project after creating it, by closing Xcode and, from terminal:

```
$ git init
$ git commit -a -m "Initial commit"
```

When i reopen Xcode, it detects my local repository just fine, except for the fact that i just can't get how to create a tag. I can create a branch, but not a tag. How do you create one from Xcode?

**EDIT:** Did what @edc1591 suggested, and even created a project with Git support from scratch and i still don't see how to create a tag. There's only a Branch subfolder and the possibility to add one (branch), but nothing about tags...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Xcode 4 doesn't have a way to do a lot of SCM things, but it does cope with you doing most things via the command line (even while it is running).   So if you want to make a tag make sure what you want tagged is committed and then do it like you would from the command line:

```
git tag -a -m "Mostly works" project_v0.2
```

On the plus side where Xcode 4 does SCM things, it does them pretty well.  The "diff view" and blame view are both very useful, as are the status tags.

Comment: Combined with [dterm](http://decimus.net/DTerm/), commandline git is really convenient for everything beyond the basics XCode 4 does.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do `git add .` (from the project directory) after `git init`. I'm not sure if this will fix the problem though. But based off what you have, you're just making an empty git repo

Comment: The thing is "it works like that", you create an empty repo just so that it can be recognized from Xcode. Then you add every file from Xcode. I know, it's weird.

Comment: On the following page Apple says to do `git add .` when creating a repo for an existing project. That's what I've been doing and it seems to work fine. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html

Comment: Tried it, updated my question with results... there seems to be no difference with both ways of creating a project by hand, and nothing yet regarding to tags.

Comment: Hmmm...I don't really know that much about git, so I'm afraid I don't have any other ideas.